# Find mustache variables in HTML with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, mustache

I'm writing some code that parses template files, and one of the first things that I'm doing is removing all of the Mustache variables in the template. For the most part, the mustache variables look like this:

```
{{variable}}, {{#loop}}{{content}}{{/loop}}, {{^not}}{{/not}}, {{! comment }}, {{#if}}{{/if}}
```

So far, I've been using this regex replace and it's worked fine to remove all of these variables:

```
markup.replace(/\{\{[^\}\}]*\}\}/g, "")
```

I've just run into an issue though where I've found a Mustache comment that wraps some *javascript* code.

```
{{! App.doStuff('magic_string')({flag:true, flag2: true}); }}
```

- Note: The .js code inside of the comment does NOT contain `}}`.

Previously, I thought that my regex would look for `{{` up until it found a `}}` (exactly 2 in a row) (`[^\}\}]`), but this does not appear to be the case. The match is stopping once it finds a single `}` and it is unable to remove this comment from the template file because it couldn't match up the opening and closing `{{ }}`.

### Question: How should my regex be updated so that it will match from '{{' to '}}' without stopping at a single '}'?

---

Example runs:

```
"<p>{{! App.doStuff('magic_string')({flag:true, flag2: true}); }}</p>".replace(/\{\{[^\}\}]*\}\}/g, "");
"<p>{{! App.doStuff('magic_string')({flag:true, flag2: true}); }}</p>" 
// bad! - should be "<p></p>"

"<p>{{test}}</p>".replace(/\{\{[^\}\}]*\}\}/g, "");
"<p></p>" // good

"<p>{{#test}}{{.}}{{/test}}</p>".replace(/\{\{[^\}\}]*\}\}/g, "");
"<p></p>" // good

"<p>{{>partial}}</p>".replace(/\{\{[^\}\}]*\}\}/g, "");
"<p></p>" //good

"<p {{#flag}}class='fancy'{{/flag}}></p>".replace(/\{\{[^\}\}]*\}\}/g, "");
"<p class='fancy'></p>" //good
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go,

```
> "<p>{{! App.doStuff('magic_string')({flag:true, flag2: true}); }}</p>".replace(/\{\{(?:(?!}}).)*\}\}/g, "")
'<p></p>'
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nO7oI6/1)

**Explanation:**

```
\{                       '{'
\{                       '{'
(?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                         times):
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
    }}                       '}}'
  )                        end of look-ahead
  .                        any character except \n
)*                       end of grouping
\}                       '}'
\}                       '}'
```

Comment: I noticed that this Regex pattern fails on multiline comments `"{{! this is \n\n a comment }}"` I've updated my question to include a comment with newline characters.

Comment: Nevermind: I stripped the string of tabs and newlines prior to running the regex and it fixed the problem.

Comment: @CoryDanielson use this regex http://regex101.com/r/nO7oI6/4 if the string contains newline chars inbetween.